# how to embed plain text data into a pdf with latex

Tags: hyperref, urls, embedding

Is there a way to embed data (e.g. CSV data) into a PDF. I want to have a table with numeric data and the reader should be able to get the data directly, without need to copy & paste from the pdf (which often doesn't work).

Using a data URI, it's possible to create a link that contains the data itself. For example putting `data:text/plain;charset=utf-8;base64,MSAyIDMNCjQgNSA2` as into a html-link will lead to a 'website' showing the plain text data:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

I tried putting this into a PDF with latex, using `\href{URI}{click here to get data}` in the pdf, but clicking on the link, nothing happens (it only works if I copy and paste the link in a browser).

Is there some way of embedding the machine-readable data of the table?

Here's what I have done so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
 \centering
 \begin{tabular}{ccc}
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
 \end{tabular}
 \caption{To get the data, click \href{data:text/plain;charset=utf-8;base64,MSAyIDMNCjQgNSA2}{here}.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post a full minimal example code?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I added a minimum (not) working example.

Comment: PDF viewers can have problems with the protocol `data:`. Some (evince, sumatraPDF) at least allow to copy the target URL. Then the URL can be copied to the address bar of  a browser to show the numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Files can be embedded using the `attachfile` package. However, opening the embedded file does not work with all pdf viewers, e.g., it works in Adobe Reader but it does not work (properly) in Evince.

Note that the file is actually embedded in the pdf, i.e., you don't need to provide the file separately when distributing your document.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{attachfile}
\begin{document}
The csv file is attached: \attachfile{embed.csv}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: this is almost perfect - I'll accept it. I wish this was supported more widely by pdf viewers tough.

Answer (score 2):

I here use features of the `accsupp` package.  Here I introduce `csvtabular` environment that typesets the `tabular` in the normal way, but using a copy/paste on the PDF, produces CSV style output.

It does this, by taking `\BODY` that the `environ` package provides and using a `listofitems` parsing to replace `&` with `,` and replace `\\` with `\n`.  Note that having a trailing `\\` on the last row of data, while innocuous to `tabular`, will break `csvtabular`...don't do it!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accsupp,environ,listofitems}
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{csvtabular}[1]{
  \setsepchar{\\/&}%
  \readlist*\mylist{\BODY}%
  \def\tmp{}%
  \foreachitem\myrow\in\mylist{%
    \foreachitem\mycol\in\mylist[1]{%
      \ifnum\mycolcnt=1\else\g@addto@macro\tmp{, }\fi%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\g@addto@macro%
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\tmp\expandafter%
           \expandafter\expandafter{\mylist[\myrowcnt,\mycolcnt]}
    }%
    \g@addto@macro\tmp{\string\n }%
  }%
  \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText={\tmp}}
  \begin{tabular}{#1}
  \BODY
  \end{tabular}
  \EndAccSupp{}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
 \centering
 \begin{csvtabular}{ccc}
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  4 & 5 & 6 
 \end{csvtabular}
 \caption{To get the data, highlight the tabular data and copy/paste.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is what you get when you copy and paste the tabular data:

```
1, 2, 3\n4, 5, 6\n
```

**ORIGINAL (MANUAL) APPROACH**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
 \centering
 \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText={1, 2, 3<CR> 4, 5, 6<CR>}}
 \begin{tabular}{ccc}
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  4 & 5 & 6 \\
 \end{tabular}
 \EndAccSupp{}
 \caption{To get the data, highlight the tabular data and copy/paste.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ok, this is already much better than the attempt to copy from the table as it was, but it's not quite as convenient as I'd like it to be.

Comment: Numbers are not problematic, thus method `plain` can be used to get new line characters (`\n` via `\string\n`): `\BeginAccSupp{method=plain,ActualText={1, 2, 3\string\n4, 5, 6}}`

Comment: @JohnSmith I fully understand.

Comment: @JohnSmith I have autoencapsulated the process into the environment `csvtabular`.